# buck compile error: "zip file is empty"

Tags: buck

on my virtual-linux system centos, i compile java project with buck encounter the following errors. While in the same directory, compile under Ubuntu is ok. Can any could help me 
solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
   buck build //marvel/incr_server:marvel_incr_server
Not using buckd because watchman isn't installed.
[-] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 0.7s
[+] BUILDING...1.2s (214/248 JOBS)
 |=> //thirdparty/buck/deps:hbase-protocol-gdt...  0.0s (checking local cache)
 |=> //thirdparty/buck/deps:hbase-rest...  0.0s (checking local cache)
[2015-09-09 15:16:32.883][error][command:14f5ac38-ec8b-41e5-8a01-56078d1661be][tid:13][com.facebook.buck.event.listener.LoggingBuildListener] Error accumulating class names for /media/psf/Code/Tencent/gdt/buck-out/gen/thirdparty/buck/deps/slf4j-log4j12/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar.
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
[2015-09-09 15:16:32.884][error][command:14f5ac38-ec8b-41e5-8a01-56078d1661be][tid:13][com.facebook.buck.event.listener.LoggingBuildListener] Error accumulating class names for /media/psf/Code/Tencent/gdt/buck-out/gen/thirdparty/buck/deps/joda-time/joda-time-2.0.jar.
java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
[2015-09-09 15:16:32.889][error][command:14f5ac38-ec8b-41e5-8a01-56078d1661be][tid:16][com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CombinedFuture] input future failed.
com.facebook.buck.step.StepFailedException: //thirdparty/buck/deps:slf4j-log4j12 failed with exit code 1:
get_class_names
    at com.facebook.buck.step.StepFailedException.createForFailingStepWithExitCode(StepFailedException.java:57)
    at com.facebook.buck.step.DefaultStepRunner.runStepInternal(DefaultStepRunner.java:105)
    at com.facebook.buck.step.DefaultStepRunner.runStepForBuildTarget(DefaultStepRunner.java:83)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine.executeCommandsNowThatDepsAreBuilt(CachingBuildEngine.java:501)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine.buildOnceDepsAreBuilt(CachingBuildEngine.java:380)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine.access$3(CachingBuildEngine.java:304)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine$1.onSuccess(CachingBuildEngine.java:181)
    at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine$1.onSuccess(CachingBuildEngine.java:1)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1319)
[-] PROCESSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 0.7s
[+] BUILDING...1.3s (228/248 JOBS)
```

Comment: the directory is actually host on my mac, so the two virtual machine could visit it both.

Comment: Are those jars empty by chance?

Comment: nope. Maybe our buck is too old

Comment: It would be worthwhile to update your Buck.  We put in a lot of changes every week to improve it.